# Estimate Gas Price (not Gas) using Web3

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-deployment, gas, javascript

Using Web3, we are able to estimate the amount of gas needed for a transaction

```
let estimatedGas = web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
})

contractObject.deploy().send({gas:estimatedGas, gasPrice: 2e9, ...})
```

**Question:** How can we estimate the `gasPrice` to use, instead of defining a static value like 2 Gwei?

Answer (score 9):

Average gas price can be calculated (as a median for the last several blocks) by using the following code:

```
web3.eth.getGasPrice().then((result) => {
console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether'))
})
```

Comment: Do you know how they estimate 'slow....fast" gas prices? I'm looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ETHGasStation.info](https://ethgasstation.info/) by sending a GET request to this URL of their API:

https://ethgasstation.info/json/ethgasAPI.json

This yields a response like this:

```
{
  "average": 46,
  "fastestWait": 0.5,
  "fastWait": 0.7,
  "fast": 131,
  "safeLowWait": 2.9,
  "blockNum": 6545673,
  "avgWait": 2.6,
  "block_time": 15.095744680851064,
  "speed": 0.5118320026004425,
  "fastest": 400,
  "safeLow": 40
}
```

The `average` field contains the GasPrice you should use for an average transaction wait time. `safeLow` contains the minimum price you should use at the moment. If you're in a rush, use `fastest`.

Comment: How are they calculating these values though?

Comment: See the FAQ: https://ethgasstation.info/faq/gas-price-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

I think that we can just simply use [web3.eth.gasPrice](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgasprice) to get the suggest gas price.